# How to write a conditional Sample combinator with Rx.Net

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a situation where I wish to sample an observable but given specific conditions I would like to accept every event. This is my attempt but I have a feeling it is unsafe due continual resubscribing to the main sequence. For example if the sampling keeps getting switched on and off and the main sequence always generates a value on subscription then I think I will get duplicate events all the time.

```
IObservable<T>
SampleMaybe<T>
    ( this IObservable<T> @this
    , IObservable<<IObservable<T>>> sample  
    )
{
    return sample
        .Select(s => s != null ? @this.Sample(s) : @this)
        .Switch();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your `.Sample(s)` call. I think the two sides of the ternary operator end up being the same.

Having said that, I think your original approach is solid, provided subscribing has no side-effects. Here's an example that maintains the subscriptions, so you even avoid that:

```
public static IObservable<T> SampleSometimes<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan sampleTime, IObservable<bool> isSamplingOn)
{
    return source.Publish(_source => _source
        .Sample(sampleTime)
        .Publish( _sampled => isSamplingOn
            .Select(b => b? _sampled : _source)
            .Switch()
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt using subjects. It keeps the original sequence hot by subscribing to it with a subject and then using the subject to feed the original sampling logic in the question.

```
public static IObservable<T> Sample<T>
   ( this IObservable<T> @this
   , IObservable<IObservable<T>> sample
   )  
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
    {
        var s = new Subject<T>();
        var d0 = sample
            .Select(s1 => s1 != null ? s.Sample(s1) : s)
            .Switch()
            .Subscribe(observer.OnNext);
        var d1 = @this.Subscribe(v => s.OnNext(v));
        return new CompositeDisposable(d0,d1);
    });

}
```